# child selectors- which one will be first and last and last-of-type?

Tags: css

I don't understand which one will be first-of-type, last-child and last-of-type?

```
<!doctype html> 
 <html>

  <head> 
   <style>
    :first-cild{color:green;}
   </style>

  </head>
  <body> 
   <div> 
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#"> One</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#">  Two </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"> Three</a> </li>
        </ul>
      <p> This is a paragraph</p>
    </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Well nothing. You spelt it wrong.

Comment: You need to tell what last child you want, like li:first-child{}

Comment: you have to specify an element to use that pseudo selector on.  Such as li:first-child

Comment: Contrary to what the two posters above me said, you don't need to provide an element to :first-c**h**ild.

Comment: You don't have to specify an element... It will just select every element that is the first child... It's just a typo error

Comment: @j08691 Correct, didn't even know that apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out by trying them and see what happens!

```css
:first-child 
{
  border:solid thin green;
}

ul:first-child 
{
  border:solid thin blue;
}

li:first-of-type
{
  border:solid thin red;
}

li:last-of-type
{
  border:solid thin orange;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html> 
 <html>
  <body> 
   <div> 
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#"> One</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#">  Two </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"> Three</a> </li>
        </ul>
      <p> This is a paragraph</p>
    </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have been trying to crack the child selector for last one hour and now realized that my editor doesn't show this in the preview. I had to run it separately on browser and it showed up. Thanks for giving example. That helped.

Comment: Was wondering what is the difference between li:first-child and li:first-of-type. Because they both do the exact same thing.

Comment: Try putting a tag other than <li> before the first <li>... What happens?

Comment: Thank you once again. I put <p> before <li> and as it is not <ul> child, then css applies style to anything that comes before the <li>. correct?